# While loop function in C language to create a tank to sum my annual increment

Tags: c, function, ubuntu, unix, while-loop

Hi guys I would like to calculate the annual increment of my water flux every year of simulation using a while loop. My model can simulate every year water flux. For example:

```
double WaterTank = 0;
s->value[FLUX_WATER];
s->value[MAX_WATER];

if (s->value[FLUX_WATER] > 0.) {

while (WaterTank <= s->value[MAX_WATER]) {

     WaterTank = WaterTank + s->value[FLUX_WATER];

     WaterTank++;

}
```

The first problem is: my water flux usually is 0.35ml per year and I put the limit of 1l to the MAX_WATER before emptying.
The second one is: I can't increment ++(1 unit) because my cycle stopped early.
I would like to sum every year until my tank reaches 1 liter (e.g 1year >> 0.35 >> 2ndyear 0.35 + 0.15 >> 3rd year 0.5 + 0.4 >> 4th year 0.9 + 0.1 (stop))

Any help? thank you!!

Comment: `s->value[FLUX_WATER];` doesn't do anything when it's alone on a line.

Comment: Why do you do `WaterTank++` after adding the flux?

Comment: I don't understand the numbers in your example. Which of them is `s->value[FLUX_WATER]`? If that's `0.35`, where do `0.15` and `0.4` come from?

Comment: In another file.c there is a vector (s->value[FLUX_WATER]) that my model calculates. But you can think in this case my flux water is 0.35ml per year of simulation. I want sum every year that 0.35ml to fill my WaterTank till 1l

Comment: If it's a vector, you need to index it. `s->value[FLUX_WATER][i]`

Comment: it works but the problem is if I put WaterTank++ the results is 1.35ml for the first year. The second year is 1.35 + 0.15 = 1.50ml and so on. I don't want the count of increment (++) in my sum but only the result of 0.35 + 0.15 and so on.

Comment: If you don't want the `++`, why did you do it?

Comment: Maybe that should be `year++` so you can count how many years it takes to fill the tank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if you've gone over `MAX_WATER` after you add the flux, and cap it to the limit.

```
while (true) {
    WaterTank += s->value[FLUX_WATER];
    if (WaterTank > s->value[MAX_WATER]) {
        WaterTank = s->value[MAX_WATER];
        break;
    }
}
```